# .htaccess Redirect Issue, Conflicting With Rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am currently having an issue with redirects in my .htaccess file which is conflicting with a rewrite rule that is used for serving pages in our CMS.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

Redirect 301 /test-page http://www.example.com/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?slug=$1
```

The problem is when I go to http://www.example.com/test-page, I get redirected to http://www.example.com/?slug=test-page rather than http://www.example.com.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
#this one prevents /test-page from further processing
RewriteRule ^test-page - [L]
```

between the redirect 301 and your other conditions.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what this is doing? The only issue I can see is that I have around 200+ redirects and would this need to be done for each one where this issue is occurring?

Comment: it depends what you want to do.

Comment: The other redirects are all similar, and having the same issue, would I need to have a rewrite rule like this for each one or is there a way to do this for a group of redirects or something like that?

Comment: if you have some pattern, there is some kind of doing this.